# error when using itertools.count() to count

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
counter = itertools.count()

dtype = [('clf', object), ('accu', float), ("counter", int)]
self.models = np.zeros((n_randoms*n_boot, n_estimators), dtype=dtype)

for i in tqdm(range(n_randoms*n_boot)):
    for j in range(n_estimators):
        clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state = j, criterion="entropy")
        clf.fit(X_train_list[i], y_train_list[i])
        accu_list[i, j] = clf.score(X_test_list[i], y_test_list[i])
        self.models[i, j] = (clf, accu_list[i, j], next(counter))

self.sorted_models = np.sort(self.models, axis=1, order=["accu", "counter"])
```

where n_randoms is 10, n_boot is 7, and I received an error that **TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'DecisionTreeClassifier' and 'DecisionTreeClassifier'** when I set n_estimators to 19, it goes well up to 18.

Theoretically, whenever two Classifier have the same accuracy, I use a next(counter) to index every Classifier so that when I use np.sort(), it sort based on the order ["accu", "counter"], which I think is fine. In addition, if I use -next(counter) instead of a plus sign here, I can only set n_estimators up to 16, and it gets the same error beginning from 17. Based on this, I think there is an error probably when I deal with next(counter).

My question is, 1.where is my error? 2.Any hints on fix it? Thank you.

Edit:
I do some more experiments, this time I set n_randoms to 100, and n_estimators to 5, which is larger than the above error numbers of iterations in total(5*100*7 > 19*10*7), but it works fine, so I guess only when the number of estimators goes up will cause an error.

Comment: ["A single field can be specified as a string, and not all fields need be specified, but **unspecified fields will still be used, in the order in which they come up in the dtype, to break ties**."](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, thanks, "but unspecified fields will still be used, in the order in which they come up in the dtype, to break ties.", my understanding is that because next(counter) will always goes up from 0, there will not be any ties, so "clf" field will not be considered. In addition, if your statement is True, why there is no problem when n_estimators is small?

Comment: I would guess either you're hitting a case where an element happens to be compared to itself, or the sort routine is comparing the extra fields eagerly.

Comment: What NumPy version is this?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I am using NumPy: 1.18.2, and run on Google Colab Pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.sort` doesn't promise not to compare elements against themselves. The [partition logic](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.18.2/numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c.src#L484-L499) in the quicksort will sometimes perform self-comparisons at the end of a partition, since the element comparison happens before the pointer comparison:

```c
/*
 * Generic comparisons may be buggy, so don't rely on the sentinels
 * to keep the pointers from going out of bounds.
 */
for (;;) {
    do {
        pi += elsize;
    } while (cmp(pi, vp, arr) < 0 && pi < pj);
    do {
        pj -= elsize;
    } while (cmp(vp, pj, arr) < 0 && pi < pj);
    if (pi >= pj) {
        break;
    }
    GENERIC_SWAP(pi, pj, elsize);
}
```

Here, `vp` is a pointer to a copy of the pivot, and the pivot is placed at the initial value of `pj`. If the pivot is the highest value in the range from the initial `pi` to the initial `pj`, then `pi` advances all the way to the pivot and self-comparison occurs.

[Pivot selection](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/464f79eb1d05bf938d16b49da1c39a4e02506fa3/numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c.src#L470-L483) would have guaranteed the existence of a value higher than the pivot, except that that higher value is placed immediately *after* the initial `pj`.

---

In a self-comparison, the counter values will be equal, and the comparison will try to ask whether a classifier is less than itself.

Partitions only start happening at all once the sort axis grows beyond the insertion sort threshold, which is why you only saw the problem when your sort axis got long enough.

Avoiding self-comparison *would* be handy. I'm pretty sure the built-in `sorted` function avoids self-comparison, and I don't think it would be too difficult to avoid self-comparison in `numpy.sort`. This might be worth an enhancement request.